# Php serialize and unserialize through form POST

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have set a number of hidden form inputs to have a value of a serialised array as shown in the example below:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"attName\" value=\"".htmlentities(serialize($attributeName))."\" />";
```

The script that receives the form post successfully gets the serialised array. If I print it out with:

```
echo "<p>".$_POST['attType']."</p>";
```

It prints out: 
a:4:{i:0;s:13:\"Serial Number\";i:1;s:5:\"works\";i:2;s:3:\"Gen\";i:3;s:4:\"test\";}
This is valid, and seems to work ok.

However, if I try and unserialize it, nothing seems to happen. This code:

```
$attName=$_POST['attName'];
echo $attName;
$attName=unserialize($attName);
echo "Array: ";
print_r($attName);
```

prints out: 
a:4:{i:0;s:13:\"Serial Number\";i:1;s:5:\"works\";i:2;s:3:\"Gen\";i:3;s:4:\"test\";}Array:

For some reason, the php can't unserialize it. I have tried serializing and unserializing the array on the first page with the form to try and find errors but it worked fine.

The weirdest thing is that this issue only occurs on my server and not in my MAMP testing environment.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is magic_quotes_gpc on?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

> Warning
> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.
> Sets the magic_quotes state for GPC (Get/Post/Cookie) operations. When magic_quotes are on, all '
> (single-quote), " (double quote), \ (backslash) and NUL's are escaped with a backslash >automatically.

If it is on, all form post data received is escaped automaticly using "". It is recommended that you should turn off the magic_quotes_gpc.

Answer (score 0):

change your code and use `stripslashes`

```
$attName= stripslashes($_POST['attName']);
echo $attName;
$attName=unserialize($attName);
echo "Array: ";
print_r($attName);
```

see on [PHP.NET](http://php.net/stripslashes)